# calculate the average time difference between each stage

Tags: oracle

How to calculate the average time difference between each stage.

The challenge with the actual data set is not every id will go through all stages.. some will skip stages and the date is not continuous for all Id's like below.

```
id    date        status
1     1/1/18      requirement
1     1/8/18      analysis
1     ?           design
1     1/30/18     closed
2     2/1/18      requirement
2     2/18/18     closed
3     1/2/18      requirement
3     1/29/18     analysis
3     ?           accepted 
3     2/5/18      closed
```

?--we have missing dates as well

```
Expected output

id    date        status      time_spent
1     1/1/18      requirement   0
1     1/8/18      analysis      7
1     ?           design       
1     1/30/18     closed        22
2     2/1/18      requirement   0
2     2/18/18     closed         17
3     1/2/18      requirement    0
3     1/29/18     analysis       27
3     ?           accepted       
3     2/5/18      closed         24      

status         avg(timespent)
requirement     0
analysis        17
design    
closed          21
```

Comment: Maybe we can help If you tell us how calculate the average

Comment: its just one table as described above. Just need expert help on to write a query that will calc the time diff based on available stages. Average would be total Id's AVG time spent on a given stage

Comment: So what is the rule for handling stages with no dates?

Comment: Read the links above. We can't help if you don't explain what to do with the nulls dates, how many stages are, etc.

Comment: Skip to next available stage. We have total 4 stages stages as below.{requirement
analysis
design
closed}

Comment: Show us what result you expect for that data, and what have you tried.

Comment: Your requirements seem a little off -- you will always show zero days spend in the "requirements" status?  Wouldn't it be better to count the days to the next status rather than days since the prior status?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use windowing functions `LAG` (or `LEAD`) to get the data of the previous (or next) status for each id.  That will let you compute the time elapsed in each stage.  Then, compute the average time elapsed for each stage.

Here is an example of how to do that:

```
with input_data (id, dte, status) as (
SELECT 1, TO_DATE('1/1/18','MM/DD/YY'), 'requirement' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, TO_DATE('1/8/18','MM/DD/YY'), 'analysis' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, NULL, 'design' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, TO_DATE('1/30/18','MM/DD/YY'), 'closed' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, TO_DATE('2/1/18','MM/DD/YY'), 'requirement' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, TO_DATE('2/18/18','MM/DD/YY'), 'closed' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, TO_DATE('1/2/18','MM/DD/YY'), 'requirement' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, TO_DATE('1/29/18','MM/DD/YY'), 'analysis' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, NULL, 'accepted' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, TO_DATE('2/5/18','MM/DD/YY'), 'closed' FROM DUAL ),
----- Solution begins here
data_with_elapsed_days as (
SELECT id.*, dte-nvl(lag(dte ignore nulls) over ( partition by id order by dte ), dte) elapsed
from input_data id)
SELECT status, avg(elapsed)
FROM data_with_elapsed_days d
group by status
order by decode(status,'requirement',1,'analysis',2,'design',3,'accepted',4,'closed',5,99);


+-------------+-------------------------------------------+
|   STATUS    |               AVG(ELAPSED)                |
+-------------+-------------------------------------------+
| requirement |                                         0 |
| analysis    |                                        17 |
| design      |                                           |
| accepted    |                                           |
| closed      | 15.33333333333333333333333333333333333333 |
+-------------+-------------------------------------------+
```

As I said in my comment, that logic computes the elapsed days as the time to the given status from the *prior* status.  Since, "requirement" has no prior status, this logic will always show zero days spent in requirements.  It would probably be better to compute the time from the given status to the *next* status.  For "closed", there would be no next status.  You could just leave that blank or use `SYSDATE` as the data of the next status.  Here is an example of that:

```
with input_data (id, dte, status) as (
SELECT 1, TO_DATE('1/1/18','MM/DD/YY'), 'requirement' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, TO_DATE('1/8/18','MM/DD/YY'), 'analysis' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, NULL, 'design' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, TO_DATE('1/30/18','MM/DD/YY'), 'closed' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, TO_DATE('2/1/18','MM/DD/YY'), 'requirement' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, TO_DATE('2/18/18','MM/DD/YY'), 'closed' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, TO_DATE('1/2/18','MM/DD/YY'), 'requirement' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, TO_DATE('1/29/18','MM/DD/YY'), 'analysis' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, NULL, 'accepted' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, TO_DATE('2/5/18','MM/DD/YY'), 'closed' FROM DUAL ),
----- Solution begins here
data_with_elapsed_days as (
SELECT id.*, nvl(lead(dte ignore nulls) over ( partition by id order by dte ), trunc(sysdate))-dte elapsed
from input_data id)
SELECT status, avg(elapsed)
FROM data_with_elapsed_days d
group by status
order by decode(status,'requirement',1,'analysis',2,'design',3,'accepted',4,'closed',5,99);



+-------------+------------------------------------------+
|   STATUS    |               AVG(ELAPSED)               |
+-------------+------------------------------------------+
| requirement |                                       17 |
| analysis    |                                     14.5 |
| design      |                                          |
| accepted    |                                          |
| closed      | 361.666666666666666666666666666666666667 |
+-------------+------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you sir. Very helpful

Comment: I thought your query and the query proposed by APC above should return similar results, but i do get quite a different counts.. Can you please shed some light here..what is the difference in your both queries

Comment: The main difference I see is that my version uses SYSDATE to compute the time spent in the most recent status (usually "closed").  Other than that, I think they're basically the same.

Comment: Do u see any issue with this to calculate the %age of each stage **COUNT(NVL(status, 0))/ round(avg(elapsed))** This doesn't seem work

Comment: can u plz me help on how to derive the right %age of each stage for the above solution?

Comment: @sunnybabau This isn't a code writing service.  It's a question-and-answer forum.  If you have a second question, you should post a second question.  If your original question has been answered to your satisfaction, you should upvote and accept that answer.

Comment: Sorry. Done accepted the solution. Was just trying to get your expert advice on what is wrong with my code in getting Average %age calculated

Comment: In the final `SELECT` (4th to last line), include '100*ratio_to_report(avg(elapsed)) over () pct`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @MatthewMcPeak. Your requirements seem a bit odd: you spend zero days of `requirement` stage but spend an average of 21 days on `closed`? Fnord.

This solution treats the presented date as the **start** date of the stage and calculates the difference between it and the start_date of the next phase.

```
with cte as (
    select status
           , lead(dd ignore nulls) over (partition by id order by dd) - dd as dt_diff
    from your_table)
select status, avg(dt_diff) as avg_ela
from cte
group by status
/
```

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak - nope, it's a legacy issue which I'd already edited :)

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to include all stages for each `d` and estimate the time spent in each (using linear interpolation) then you can create a sub-query with all the statuses and use a `PARTITION OUTER JOIN` to join them and then use `LAG` and `LEAD` to find the date range the status is in and interpolate between:

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE data ( d, dt, status ) AS
SELECT 1, TO_DATE( '1/1/18', 'MM/DD/YY' ),  'requirement' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, TO_DATE( '1/8/18', 'MM/DD/YY' ),  'analysis'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, NULL,                             'design'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, TO_DATE( '1/30/18', 'MM/DD/YY' ), 'closed'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, TO_DATE( '2/1/18', 'MM/DD/YY' ),  'requirement' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, TO_DATE( '2/18/18', 'MM/DD/YY' ), 'closed'      FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, TO_DATE( '1/2/18', 'MM/DD/YY' ),  'requirement' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, TO_DATE( '1/29/18', 'MM/DD/YY' ), 'analysis'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, NULL,                             'accepted'    FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, TO_DATE( '2/5/18', 'MM/DD/YY' ),  'closed'      FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
WITH statuses ( status, id ) AS (
  SELECT 'requirement', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'analysis',    2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'design',      3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'accepted',    4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'closed',      5 FROM DUAL
),
ranges ( d, dt, status, id, recent_dt, recent_id, next_dt, next_id ) AS (
  SELECT d.d,
         d.dt,
         s.status,
         s.id,
         NVL(
           d.dt,
           LAG( d.dt, 1 )
             IGNORE NULLS OVER ( PARTITION BY d.d ORDER BY s.id )
         ),
         NVL2(
           d.dt,
           s.id,
           LAG( CASE WHEN d.dt IS NOT NULL THEN s.id END, 1 )
             IGNORE NULLS OVER ( PARTITION BY d.d ORDER BY s.id )
         ),
         LEAD( d.dt, 1, d.dt )
           IGNORE NULLS OVER ( PARTITION BY d.d ORDER BY s.id ),
         LEAD( CASE WHEN d.dt IS NOT NULL THEN s.id END, 1, s.id + 1 )
           IGNORE NULLS OVER ( PARTITION BY d.d ORDER BY s.id )
  FROM   data d
         PARTITION BY ( d )
         RIGHT OUTER JOIN statuses s
         ON ( d.status = s.status )
)
SELECT d,
       dt,
       status,
       ( next_dt - recent_dt ) / (next_id - recent_id ) AS estimated_duration
FROM   ranges;
```

**Output**:

```
 D | DT        | STATUS      |                       ESTIMATED_DURATION
-: | :-------- | :---------- | ---------------------------------------:
 1 | 01-JAN-18 | requirement |                                        7
 1 | 08-JAN-18 | analysis    | 7.33333333333333333333333333333333333333
 1 | null      | design      | 7.33333333333333333333333333333333333333
 1 | null      | accepted    | 7.33333333333333333333333333333333333333
 1 | 30-JAN-18 | closed      |                                        0
 2 | 01-FEB-18 | requirement |                                     4.25
 2 | null      | analysis    |                                     4.25
 2 | null      | design      |                                     4.25
 2 | null      | accepted    |                                     4.25
 2 | 18-FEB-18 | closed      |                                        0
 3 | 02-JAN-18 | requirement |                                       27
 3 | 29-JAN-18 | analysis    | 2.33333333333333333333333333333333333333
 3 | null      | design      | 2.33333333333333333333333333333333333333
 3 | null      | accepted    | 2.33333333333333333333333333333333333333
 3 | 05-FEB-18 | closed      |                                        0
```

**Query 2**:

Then of you can easily change that to take the average for each status:

```
WITH statuses ( status, id ) AS (
  SELECT 'requirement', 1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'analysis',    2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'design',      3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'accepted',    4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'closed',      5 FROM DUAL
),
ranges ( d, dt, status, id, recent_dt, recent_id, next_dt, next_id ) AS (
  SELECT d.d,
         d.dt,
         s.status,
         s.id,
         NVL(
           d.dt,
           LAG( d.dt, 1 )
             IGNORE NULLS OVER ( PARTITION BY d.d ORDER BY s.id )
         ),
         NVL2(
           d.dt,
           s.id,
           LAG( CASE WHEN d.dt IS NOT NULL THEN s.id END, 1 )
             IGNORE NULLS OVER ( PARTITION BY d.d ORDER BY s.id )
         ),
         LEAD( d.dt, 1, d.dt )
           IGNORE NULLS OVER ( PARTITION BY d.d ORDER BY s.id ),
         LEAD( CASE WHEN d.dt IS NOT NULL THEN s.id END, 1, s.id + 1 )
           IGNORE NULLS OVER ( PARTITION BY d.d ORDER BY s.id )
  FROM   data d
         PARTITION BY ( d )
         RIGHT OUTER JOIN statuses s
         ON ( d.status = s.status )
)
SELECT status,
       AVG( ( next_dt - recent_dt ) / (next_id - recent_id ) ) AS estimated_duration
FROM   ranges
GROUP BY status, id
ORDER BY id;
```

**Results**:

```
STATUS      |                       ESTIMATED_DURATION
:---------- | ---------------------------------------:
requirement |                                    12.75
analysis    | 4.63888888888888888888888888888888888889
design      | 4.63888888888888888888888888888888888889
accepted    | 4.63888888888888888888888888888888888889
closed      |                                        0
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d74180afb60455f56ef66c2f59b24341)*

Comment: Thank you for the logic